# Cannot install webtorrent in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webtorrent

Cannot install `npm install webtorrent` tried older versions and hybrid too.

**this is the error I got**

[image]

Thank you for helping me in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the webpack section https://github.com/feross/webtorrent. It explains you need to add couple of lines of configuration to make it work.

```
{
  target: 'web',
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // make sure to install the 'json-loader' package: npm install json-loader
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'mm so sorry. If you don't mind can you tell me how to do that?